# jQuery undefined variable markercluster

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, marker

I have a google maps with a bunch of markers. When you zoom out, you must see the marker clusters:
http://libris.houston-1.hybridmedia.be/nl/het-project/

I always get the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: MarkerCluster is not defined

But the markercluster.js file is included correctly. Now I'm completely lost what to do :(

Comment: Perhaps you could add more definition to where exactly in your code you throw the error or how you are importing MarkerCluster? From the compiled code I can only see the MarkerCluster is not getting imported from anywhere before you call `var mc = new MarkerCluster(map)`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue **in the question itself**, not (just) a link to a non-working site.

Comment: @K.F First I load the markerclusterer.js file:
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-marker-clusterer/1.0.0/markerclusterer.js?ver=4.9.6"></script>

and then I load my custom script.

So the MarkerClusterer file is being imported it guess? :/

Comment: Did you figure something out? from the docs it seems like you may have been using the wrong constructor name? https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/reference.html (Should be `MarkerClusterer`)

Comment: @K.F yes, it was indeed a wrong constructor. I've added my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed. I wrote indeed a typo "MarkerCluster" had to be "MarkerClusterer".
I've also re-wrote the loadMarkers function a little bit

```
function loadMarkers(map) {

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    geojson_url = '/project.geojson';

    jQuery.getJSON(geojson_url, function(result) {
       data = result['locations'];
       jQuery.each(data, function(key, val) {
           var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(val['geometry']['coordinates'][0]), parseFloat(val['geometry']['coordinates'][1]));
           var titleText = val['properties']['name'];    
           var address = val['geometry']['address'];
           var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: point,
               title: titleText,
               icon: icons[val['type']].icon,
               map: map,
               properties: val['type']
            });
            var markerInfo = "<div><h3>" + titleText + "</h3> " + address + "</div>";
            marker.addListener('click', function() {
              infoWindow.close();
              infoWindow.setContent(markerInfo);
              infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
            markers.push(marker);
          });
          var Marker = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
          Marker.addMarkers(markers);
      });
    }
```

I had to add the imagePath from the markers in order to make it work.